# How to load redis rdb data into running redis server without losing redis data?

Tags: database, redis, redis-server

I have 2 redis server. If I have backup of one redis server (example.rdb), then how to load this data to another running redis server without losing current memory data ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [rdb command from redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) with the `-c protocol` option to [output redis commands](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools#emitting-redis-protocol) representing the data in the RDB file, and pipe them into a redis instance using netcat, socat, or similar.

Unfortunately, this python package was built for now unsupported python 2.7 and 3.5 and has not been updated since 2020 (see [FAQs](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/FAQs)).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the version number 10 that doesn't work with redis-rdb-tools.

I have to use an alternative:
https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-rdb-cli